# Overlapping span's on hover without displacement

Tags: html, css

Well this is for texts, here is the code I was trying:

```css
<style>
#items { 
     width:400px;
     padding: 10px;
}

.esp {
 float: left;
 background-color: yellow;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
}  
.le {
 float: left;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;

}  

.esp:hover{
 background-color: blue;
    z-index:1;
    /*width: 50px;*/
    border: 20px solid;
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>

<div id="items">

<span class="le">fist</span>
<span class="le">fist</span>
<span class="le">fist</span>
<span class="le">fist</span>
<span class="le">fist</span>
<span class="esp">second</span>
<span class="le">third</span>
<span class="le">fist</span>
<span class="esp">second</span>
<span class="le">third</span>
<span class="le">fist</span>
<span class="esp">second</span>
<span class="le">third</span>
<span class="le">third</span>
<span class="le">third</span>
<span class="le">third</span>

</div>


</html>
```

What i'm looking for is to avoid the displacement of the others span, seems like *z-index* property doesn't work. Something like this:
[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are increasing the size of the span's box, but not telling other elements to ignore that. `relative` only lets you relatively position- it doesn't remove from flow, and `z-index` only does something if an element would be displayed on top of or behind you- it doesn't effect x/y positioning. However, we will need to set it higher than our younger sibling(s) in order to have our outlining effect display in front of them.

A negative margin with the same width as the border can solve this problem.

Another, more DRY solution would be to use `outline` or `box-shadow` instead of `border`, as both `outline` and `box-shadow` are drawn outside of the box.

Note that `outline` outlines around children as well, so if you abs-pos any children to where they're outside of the parent, the box will be drawn around them as well. However, it is most semantically correct for what you're trying to do.

```css
#items { 
     width:400px;
     padding: 10px;
}

.esp {
 float: left;
 background-color: yellow;
    position:relative;
}  
.le {
 float: left;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;

}  

/*border-neg-margins*/
/*dis: neg margins*/
.bnm:hover{
    background-color: blue;
    z-index:1; 
    border: 20px solid #556;
    margin: -20px;
}

/*outline*/
/*adv: no negative margins, most semantically correct*/
/*dis: will expand to outline any children that exceed the parent's size*/
.ol:hover{
    background-color: blue;
    z-index:1; 
    outline: 20px solid #556;
}

/*box-shadow*/
/*adv: no neg margins, only outlines the box*/
/*dis: not really semantically correct*/
.bs:hover{
    background-color: blue;
    z-index:1; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px #556;
}
```

```html
The first one uses Border and Negative Margins<br />
The second uses Outline<br />
The third uses Box-Shadow<br />
Color used is #556 so any sibling text appearing on top of it would be visible<br />
<span class="le">fist</span>
<span class="le">fist</span>
<span class="le">fist</span>
<span class="le">fist</span>
<span class="le">fist</span>
<span class="esp bnm">second</span>
<span class="le">third</span>
<span class="le">fist</span>
<span class="esp ol">second</span>
<span class="le">third</span>
<span class="le">fist</span>
<span class="esp bs">second</span>
<span class="le">third</span>
<span class="le">third</span>
<span class="le">third</span>
<span class="le">third</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, but one more question, is said that you can't give `width` property to a `span` then how come the span hovered get affected when uncommented `/*width: 50px;*/` in the code I posted? .

Comment: @user2495207 `float`ing elements are automatically upgraded to `block`s if they were `inline` (or, really, most `display` property values are upgraded to their block-level equivalent). `span` doesn't accept `width` by default because `span` is a generic `inline` element by default. To see the full conversion list, refer to the table on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).

Comment: I thought `z-index` is used to specify which element is going to be behind or in front, that's why i gave `0` to all `spans` and gave `1` to the hovered element bringing it to the front, overlapping the rest without displacing them.

Comment: @user2495207 `z-index` gives some ability to override the natural stacking order (which is youngest-sibling-on-top) assuming there is any overlapping. By default, without any xy-positioning, elements will try their best to not overlap to begin with. Note that `z-index` will have no effect if the element has `position:static`, which is the default. `z-index` was still needed because lacking it would cause the younger sibling of the hovered element to appear "on top of" the outline/border/shadow. For more info on `z-index`, see the [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: @user2495207 Heh and to fully master z-index, you'll probably also wanna read [this article on stacking contexts](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/). Stacking contexts are kinda complicated until you get the hang of them.

Comment: Erm, correction to myself earlier.... Default is a lot more complicated than youngest-sibling-on-top, but I'd need to explain stacking contexts to really define it otherwise and that's pretty close to it (assuming everybody is in the same stacking context and positioning level).

Answer (score 1):

You have relative element, so it react with other elements. If you add 20px border, then other elements are reacting to this by displacement. You can place negative margin which will 'pull back' this 20px you've added with border.

```
.esp:hover{
    background-color: blue;
    z-index:1;
    border: 20px solid;
    margin: -20px;
}
```